# Why won't my site automatically apply updates after upgrade to 3.7?

Tags: updates, automatic-updates

I've just upgraded to 3.7 and one of the features in this release is the automatic application of security releases. However once I upgraded it said

> "This site is not able to apply these updates automatically. But we’ll
>   email (my email address) when there is a new security release."

What is it about my site that stops these updates being applied automatically?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer [here](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/09/24/automatic-core-updates/):

- If the install uses FTP for updates (and prompts for credentials),
  automatic updates are disabled. (I found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/23175/4661) which will tell you how to avoid using FTP.)
- If the install is running as a SVN or
  GIT checkout, automatic updates are disabled
- If the constants
  DISALLOW_FILE_MODS or AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED are defined,
  automatic updates are disabled
- If the constant WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE is
  defined as false, automatic updates are disabled
- Your WordPress
  install also needs to be able to contact WordPress.org over HTTPS
  connections, so your PHP install also needs OpenSSL installed and
  working
- Wp-Cron needs to be operational, if for some reason cron
  fails to work for your install, Automatic Updates will also be
  unavailable

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/background-update-tester/) will test these things for you.